# Flashing via OpenOCD does not allow the embedded program to run, however running using GDB with an OpenOCD bridge works fine

Tags: rust, embedded

I am running into an issue with using Rust for embedded purposes where I can run and debug programs just fine, but if I try to flash programs such that they can run without being connected to my computer they do not work.

For reference, I am using an stm32f303 chip. This also seems to be a recent issue, since I haven't had a problem before.

Code being flashed (its just blinky):

```
#![feature(used)]
#![no_std]

extern crate cortex_m;
extern crate cortex_m_rt;
extern crate panic_abort; // panicking behavior
extern crate stm32f30x_hal as hal;

use hal::prelude::*;
use hal::stm32f30x;
use hal::delay::Delay;

fn main() {
    let cp = cortex_m::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let dp = stm32f30x::Peripherals::take().unwrap();

    let mut flash = dp.FLASH.constrain();
    let mut rcc = dp.RCC.constrain();

    let clocks = rcc.cfgr.freeze(&mut flash.acr);

    let mut gpioc = dp.GPIOC.split(&mut rcc.ahb);

    let mut led1 = gpioc
        .pc13
        .into_push_pull_output(&mut gpioc.moder, &mut gpioc.otyper);

    let mut delay = Delay::new(cp.SYST, clocks);

    loop {
        led1.set_high();
        delay.delay_ms(1_000_u16);
        led1.set_low();
        delay.delay_ms(1_000_u16);
    }
}

// As we are not using interrupts, we just register a dummy catch all
// handler
#[link_section = ".vector_table.interrupts"]
#[used]
static INTERRUPTS: [extern "C" fn(); 240] = [default_handler; 240];

extern "C" fn default_handler() {
    loop {}
}
```

Output of OpenOCD program command:

```
$ openocd -f interface/jlink.cfg -f target/stm32f3x.cfg -c "program target/thumbv7em-none-eabihf/debug/cortex-m-quickstart verify reset exit"

Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "jtag". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
jtag_ntrst_delay: 100
none separate
cortex_m reset_config sysresetreq
Info : No device selected, using first device.
Info : J-Link EDU Mini V1 compiled Mar 16 2017 12:04:38
Info : Hardware version: 1.00
Info : VTarget = 3.178 V
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Info : JTAG tap: stm32f3x.cpu tap/device found: 0x4ba00477 (mfg: 0x23b (ARM Ltd.), part: 0xba00, ver: 0x4)
Info : JTAG tap: stm32f3x.bs tap/device found: 0x06422041 (mfg: 0x020 (STMicroelectronics), part: 0x6422, ver: 0x0)
Info : stm32f3x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
Info : JTAG tap: stm32f3x.cpu tap/device found: 0x4ba00477 (mfg: 0x23b (ARM Ltd.), part: 0xba00, ver: 0x4)
Info : JTAG tap: stm32f3x.bs tap/device found: 0x06422041 (mfg: 0x020 (STMicroelectronics), part: 0x6422, ver: 0x0)
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x1ffff1bc msp: 0x20001258
Info : Reduced speed from 8000 kHz to 4000 kHz (maximum).
adapter speed: 8000 kHz
** Programming Started **
auto erase enabled
Info : device id = 0x10036422
Info : flash size = 256kbytes
wrote 14336 bytes from file target/thumbv7em-none-eabihf/debug/cortex-m-quickstart in 0.688176s (20.344 KiB/s)
** Programming Finished **
** Verify Started **
verified 13028 bytes in 0.077558s (164.041 KiB/s)
** Verified OK **
** Resetting Target **
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
Info : JTAG tap: stm32f3x.cpu tap/device found: 0x4ba00477 (mfg: 0x23b (ARM Ltd.), part: 0xba00, ver: 0x4)
Info : JTAG tap: stm32f3x.bs tap/device found: 0x06422041 (mfg: 0x020 (STMicroelectronics), part: 0x6422, ver: 0x0)
shutdown command invoked
```

As can be seen, there aren't any issues when flashing the program, however it doesn't run. Once again, everything is completely fine when using GDB, and the code runs without any issues.

Any help, advice, or even general ideas of what to do would be greatly appreciated!

**[Update]**

It looks like the issue is with my boot0 pin, which is pulled high instead of low. This means that when GDB isn't connected and setting the PC, the MCU tries to boot from system memory instead of main memory. This explains why it works when debugging but not on its own.

Comment: dump/examine the flash using the telnet interface for each approach, confirm they are writing the same bits/bytes.

Comment: instead of scripting, use the telnet interface manually

Comment: Probably your startup code or reset vector isn't correct.  Loading through the debugger doesn't actually start at the reset vector.  It grabs hold of the processor and then coerces the registers to put the PC at the "entry point"

Comment: Ah, that must be it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'm using the `cortex-m-rt` crate, but there might be some bug that was introduced recently.

Comment: Not a case with st but with some nxp chips for example there is a checksum in the vector table and the higher level tools that go through openocd will compute the checksum for you but openocd at the lower telnet access level will not, causing the code to not work.

Comment: It is likely the entry point thing, you should always diassemble/examine the vector table on a new project build before committing it to the flash to insure the tools, your makefile, etc have generated a binary that will boot.   If this is the case you can use openocd if the processor/debugger is not hung, to examine the beginning/entry point of the flash as well as the program counter address indicated when the processor was stopped, one or both may give you an indication of what happened.  (if this is a case of an improperly built binary).

Comment: you have boot0 pulled down yes when resetting the part with the new flash image?

Comment: The vector table looked good, but I double checked my boot0 pin and it looks like I screwed up the latest revision of the board I'm working on, and pulled it high. This is why it works with GDB but not otherwise! Thanks for all the help,  I've learned a lot about how to debug Arm from this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may be following the instructions in the [Embedded Rust Book](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/), if you have been using semihosting to print messages from your program while debugging (I used `cortex_m_semihosting::hprintln`), be aware that it seems to cause the same symptoms as above. I spent hours trying to figure out why the program would not start when run 'by itself', but removing the semihosting crate and the `hprintln` call immediately fixed the problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30679250)